# How to adapt old way of routing to the recent version of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am following a video tutorial on AngularJS. On the part related to $routeProvider, I got an error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective
```

and no content is displayed. Everything works however on instructor demo.
I noticed that when I substitute my angular libraries:

- angular.min.js (v1.2.26)
- angular-route.min.js (v1.3.11)

with instructor's older libraries:

- angular.min.js (v1.2.9)
- angular-route.min.js (v1.2.10)

everything works perfect.

I understand there must have been some updates to the way $routeProvider behaves with newer versions of AngularJS, so I would definitely prefer to follow these. Could anyone help me adapt the current code so that it works with most recent libraries?

my app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'artistControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
    controller: 'ListController'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/list'
  });
}]);
```

and my controllers.js:

```
var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', []);

artistControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = data;
    $scope.artistOrder = 'name';
  });
}]);
```

Comment: try passing your `artistControllers` module as a parameter to your `.config`.  `myApp.config(['$routeProvider', 'artistControllers', function($routeProvider, artistControllers) {`.  Because of changes to the way controllers are located now, I think you need the dependency, since the controllers are in a different module from the app.

Comment: Thanks @Claies, I tried your suggestion but still no luck :(